# Using Formik form validation onSubmit() doesn't get called while im pressing sumbit button. if i commented validationScheme props sumbit() get working

Tags: reactjs, formik

[My code image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiuAw.png)

its my Formik comp details, if i commented validationSchema() . onSubmit() get triggered. Help me out.

Comment: onSubmit does not trigger if there are validation errors exist

Comment: i have checked error field in formik . but there is no errors. I ll recheck again. tQ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have validation errors based on your validation schema. You can use formik.errors to see which fields are failing validation.

Comment: Ok i ll check with formik.errors. thq

Comment: Its working now . i forgot to add nullable();

Answer (score 1):

That's because there are some validation errors

Comment: OK i ll recheck again.. tq fo yur time...

Comment: Its working now . i forgot to add nullable();